# converting integer chars to numeric array in matlab

Tags: matlab, char

I have a `char` array of format `a = [1.234 ; 2.345; 3.456]` and I need to convert this to a numeric array in MATLAB. I have tried `str2num(a)` but it only seems to work on integers, as it is returning an empty vector. Here is what the data actually looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem are appreciated!

Comment: You should not add a screenshot as an example of your variable but rather copy a short version of it here.

Comment: That strange, `str2num(a)` should work. Can you provide an example to how you create such an array? You can also try `cellstr(a)`, to convert it to cell array- maybe it will work.

Answer (score 2):

If your character array is either of the following formats:

```
a = '[1.234; 2.345; 3.456]';      % 1-by-N with brackets, spaces, or semicolons
a = ['1.234'; '2.345'; '3.456'];  % M-by-N
```

Then [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) should work as you want:

```
vec = str2num(a)

vec =

   1.234000000000000
   2.345000000000000
   3.456000000000000
```

If it's not working then that probably means that your character array `val` has rows with invalid formats or characters that don't properly convert. Since the array has 3100 rows, you probably don't want to search through it by hand. One easy way to highlight where invalid rows might be is to identify where there are characters other than numbers, periods, or white space. Here's how you can get a list of rows that may warrant further inspection:

```
suspiciousRows = find(~all(ismember(val, '0123456789. '), 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `str2double` would works for your case. Please refer to [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html?s_tid=doc_ta) for detailed usage.

Comment: I have a 3100x18 `char` and it is returning a 1x1 `NaN` with `str2double`

Answer (score 0):

[`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) would work as it is but as [`str2num` uses `eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html#f76-13387),so a better alternative is [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html). But it is not directly applicable on a char array like yours. You can convert that array into a cell using  [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) and then apply `str2double`.

```
req = str2double(cellstr(val))
```

---

Another approach if you have MATLAB R2016b or a later version is to convert that char array into a [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) and then apply `str2double`.

```
req = str2double(string(val))
```